# link to go example Camel K->Pipelines->Tekton->DELEGATE BUILD TO OPERATOR is broken

Tags: tekton, apache-camel-k

the link for the example  DELEGATE BUILD TO OPERATOR for tekton is broken ?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/camel-k/main/cicd/tekton/kamel-run/0.1/samples/run-operator-build.yaml

And someone have already do template CICD ArgoCD with camel-k application route ?

thanks you

i receive a page 404: Not Found.
......................

Answer (score 0):

That is an old link that was replaced by

https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/kamel-run

This example [1] may help you also setting up a CICD with ArgoCD, I guess you may need to include the Tekton part for the generation of an Integration directly in the CICD via `kamel-run` task.

[1] https://camel.apache.org/blog/2023/07/camel-k-gitops/